# How to parse Craigslist content through RSS

Tags: javascript, rss, craigslist

Craigslist don't provide any APIs for data access.

I would like to write a small client to parse data from their RSS and reflow it.

I would like to do this without setting up a server. What client side tools/JavaScript are available out there can allows quick and easy parsing of RSS feeds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check out [Using Javascript to display RSS](http://www.newsniche.com/using-javascript-to-display-rss.php) for some links to JS clients.

Also [yahoo pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com) has some interesting ways to interact with RSS feeds

Answer (score 2):

I do not know what type of parsing you want but using Yahoo Pipes you can parse RSS and create some useful thing like this pipe : [Multicity Bike Search](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=oibdg__42xGtJOXN1vC6Jw)

- Click run to see the results
- Click on View Source to see how he did it.